Identification of cartan subalgebra and its dual - root space decomposition
For a semisimple lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ we have a root space decomposition with Cartan Subalgebra $\mathfrak{t}$. We often consider the dual $\mathfrak{t}^*$ and want to identify it with $\mathfrak{t}$.
One way I see this happening is using the standard dual basis i.e. take some basis $x_i$ of $\mathfrak{t}$ and consider the dual basis $x_i^*$ of $\mathfrak{t}^*$.
I also see that once we know the Killing form is non-degenerate we can idenify via $x \mapsto K( \cdot , x) \in \mathfrak{t}^*$.
When computing some examples for $A_r$ i.e. $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ it seemed like these identifications coincided. It feels like this was just coincidence. But in Fulton and Harris they call their basis of the CSA $H_i$ almost suggesting the identification with simple root $\alpha_i$. Does someone have any insight to this? Thanks!

The basis traditionally denoted by $H_i$ is certainly not the dual basis to the simple roots. Instead that is used for the basis of coroots. This is by analogy with the case of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and the basis $E,F,H$ where $H = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ so that $\alpha(H) = 2$.
So under the identification $\mathfrak{h} \cong \mathfrak{h}^*$ given by the Killing form, we have $H_i = \frac{2\alpha_i}{(\alpha_i,\alpha_i)}$. This basis is instead dual to basis of the fundamental weights $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_r$. You can of course change to this basis and the change of basis matrix is given by the Cartan matrix (or its transpose depending on your convention).

I don't think this really asnwers my query. To elaborate at the bottom of page 239 of https://mat.uab.cat/~pitsch/ReadingSeminar/Fulton-Harris.pdf . We see that H_i are just defined and we take L_i as dual vectors. It later turns out that the killing form identification coincided with taking duals. This feels like a coincidence?

@RickSmith That section is talking about $C_r$ rather than $A_r$ and you can see that they choose the basis to be orthonormal (up to overall scale) for the Killing form so the identifications would automatically coincide.
